# Can someone help me find where these suttas are from in the Tipitaka?

Tags: pali-canon, the-buddha, sutras, tipitaka

First text screenshot says **MLD. 131**. Where is that from?
[image]

Second text screenshot says **M. 19**. Where is that from?
[image]

Screenshots are taken from Ven. Dhammajivas book called [*Mahasi Insight Meditation*](https://www.vipassana.com/resources/box/MahasiInsightMeditation-v20-vf.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The First one is from: [BhaddekaRatta Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.131.than.html)
The Second one is from: [Maha Parinibbana Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.16.1-6.vaji.html)

I have given you the links But you cannot find the Pali text in English.  I converted into sinhala and search with sinhala words and find the related English text for you.
Those two sutta's are little bit longer one's but worthwhile reading the whole context rather than the specific place to get the full idea. Also these links may helpful for you to understand many Buddhist text in English because it has Thripitaka converted to english.
May Triple Gem bless you.

Comment: Thank you very much dear Sanath. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You are most welcome my dear this is buddhism helping each other until achieve Nibbana.  My Triple Gem Bless you until you achieve your goals!!!